# DISA-STIG compliance script for personal use

Tags: scripts, security

I saw Ubuntu Security Guide and various compliances scripts for hardening. I've never used any of these scripts before and was curious to see.

I chose the DISA-STIG script. After a reboot a strange message awaits:

'' You are accessing a U.S.Goverment (USG) Information System (IS) that is provided for USG-authorized use only. By using this IS (which includes any device attached to this IS), you consent to the following conditions:

- The USG routinely intercepts and monitors communications on this IS for purposes incuding, but not limited to, penetration testing, COMSEC monitoring, network operations and defense, personnel misconduct (PM), law enforcement (LE), and counterintelligence (CI) investigations.
- At any time, the USG may inspect and seize data stored on this IS.
- Communications using, or data stored on, this IS are not private, are subject to routine monitoring, interception, and search..."

It's just in a virtualbox VM. But regarldess...are we allowed to use it? Is privacy thrown out of the window as shown in the warning? Just wanted to check on a chance it's just a generic message nobody bothered to remove for public use.

Answer (score 0):

No - its just the banner the the script plugs in based on rules within the DISA STIG. You can change the login banner by editing the "/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults" file.